# Right syntax in an "isset(...) ? :" scheme

Tags: php

I have this line

```
$logos = isset($instance['client_logo']) ? $instance['client_logo'] : [''];
```

causing this

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in .../widget-home-clients.php on line 18

How does it need to be changed?

Comment: `$logos = isset($instance['client_logo']) ? $instance['client_logo'] : '';`

Answer (score 3):

If `['']` is intented to give you an array holding one empty string, you should do `array('')`, because it appears your PHP version doesn't yet allow for this short syntax - it was introduced with PHP 5.4.

If you just wanted to get an empty string, just replace `['']` with `''`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$logos = (isset($instance['client_logo'])) ? $instance['client_logo'] : '';
```

Comment: Why add the extra `()` ?

Comment: `()` is not mandatory.

Comment: I can also add 100 times `()` around `isset()` but why ?

Comment: No special reason. My style.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following code...

```
<?php 
$logos = '';
if(isset($instance['client_logo']) && !empty($instance['client_logo']))
{
    $logos= $instance['client_logo'];
}
?>
```